# High volume of LCK_M_SCH_M waits on METADATA: database_id = 1 SECURITY_CACHE

Tags: sql-server-2016

We are suffering very bad performance after migrating 340 databases and 74000 logins from a SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition to a SQL Server 2016 standard edition (13.0.6404.1) in a new and more powerful hardware (512 GB of Memory and 24 CPUs - 48 logical processors, the maximum this SQL Server can use). We kept all databases with SQL2012 compatibility level, expecting, at least, the same behaviour at query level.

The main reason of the bad perfromance is the wait type `LCK_M_SCH_M` waits on `METADATA: database_id = 1 SECURITY_CACHE ($hash = 0x0:0x15), lockPartitionId = 0`. Usually there are around 2000 sessions with around 25 active  (running/ runnable state) at the same time. This wait can take 10 seconds of wait time!

This wait type is impacting almost all kind of SELECT statement, even if you are querying  current logins information from dmvs or querying from a user table in a user database.
The sessions I see that are causing those locks are bit random and only running Selects, for example from our monitoring tools, like Idera or Appdynamics which I'm pretty sure they are not making any change at schema level related with Security Cache.

I think that those locks are due to SQL Server trying to figure out the permissions each session's login has in order to see it it can or not access to a particular table, for instance. But I'm not 100% sure.

Creating a server audit, I have proved that there is no logins, user or permissions changes while we see all those locks.

Thank you very much.

[image: Example of sessionn getting blocked due to Security Cache]

Comment: Perhaps a nasty logon trigger? Or a Row Level Security function? Or it might be the Audit itself which is causing it

Comment: There is no Server triggers. And there is an audit I had to create to figure out if something was continuously making changes at security level and that were the cause of the locks. I saw that there was no such thing and I disabled it.

Comment: Is it 74K logins on one instance? SQL Server allows maximum of 32,767 user connections. You could be aproaching some limit within the engine itself, which gets exposed in the newer version. Can you prune any of those logins? That aside 2016 Standard can use up to 128Gb of memory. 512 looks like an overkill and probably introduces the overhead of NUMA nodes.

Comment: Yes , there are 74k server logins created and growing, but usually there are no more than 2K sessions at the same time. The server has 512GB of memory but the SQL Server has the Max Memory set to 200GB. 128Gb is the limit for the buffer pool so we gave a bit more for the rest of memory uses. The SQL 2012 Standard edition from where we migrated had 16 cores (32 logical cpus used by the SQL) and 150 of Max Memory, and we didn't had this SECURITY_CACHE locks issues...